# Error when installing pyodbc-3.0.6 on Fedora

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to install pyodbc-3.0.6 on Fedora.

I had downloaded it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/detail?name=pyodbc-3.0.6.zip)

When I run it with `python setup.py install` it's displaying the following error

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pyodbc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pyodbc.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pyodbc.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing pyodbc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pyodbc.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pyodbc.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pyodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'tests/*'
writing manifest file 'pyodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/local
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/local/PENNYWISE
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/local/PENNYWISE/shivakrishnab
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/local/PENNYWISE/shivakrishnab/Desktop
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/local/PENNYWISE/shivakrishnab/Desktop/pyodbc-3.0.6
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/local/PENNYWISE/shivakrishnab/Desktop/pyodbc-3.0.6/src
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.6 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /home/local/user/Desktop/pyodbc-3.0.6/src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/local/user/Desktop/pyodbc-3.0.6/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Can anyone let me know how to solve this.

**Edited Code:**

After installing g++ as indicated by below command and when I run the following command

```
python setup.py install
```

from inside the pyodbc downloaded folder I got the following error

```
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.6 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /home/local/user/Desktop/pyodbc-3.0.6/src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/local/user/Desktop/pyodbc-3.0.6/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
In file included from /home/local/user/Desktop/pyodbc-3.0.6/src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
/home/local/user/Desktop/pyodbc-3.0.6/src/pyodbc.h:48:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install g++ package. `yum install compat-gcc-34-c++`
(edit: it seems they moved it to `compat-gcc-34-c++`)

[edit]

For the second issue - you are missing `unixODBC-devel` package.

For CentOS the package name is `gcc-c++`

Comment: K installed g++ with the following command yum install gcc gcc-c++ make andonce agian tried to install the same and error displayed is same as above

Comment: Ok, nevermind my edits, let e figure it out as to where fedora stuffed their cc1plus in the latest releases.

Comment: Can you try `compat-gcc-34-c++`? On my fedora it was there :)

Comment: Yes i had installed g++ by ur command and installed that successfully and edited the code above please find the same

Comment: please edit your answer to mention the gcc-c++. I am runing CentOS7 and the package name is that. I know the question is for fedora but many CentOS may see this

Answer (score 0):

To suppress the exception:

> sql.h: No file or directory in CentOS install unixODBC-devel.x86_64

Run the following command for 64-bit:

```
yum install unixODBC-devel.x86_64
```